Converting polygon annotations to vector layer in QGIS
In QGIS I mapped a large flood basin as a polygon annotation, not realizing that it would have strange properties. Is there any way I could convert this polygon annotation into a vector layer e.g. a shapefile?

I cant find a simple tool for it. But it is possible to read the geometries and create a new layer from them using pyqgis. I have an annotation layer with polygon, line and point markers.
Change the annotations layer name in the second line and execute:
#Change Annotations to the name of your layer:
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("Annotations")[0]

#Create a list of all polygon annotations
polygon_annotations_list = [] #A list to hold all polygon annotations
for i in layer.items():
   #i is an identifier for each annotation:
    #{195cc591-913b-4607-b40c-b09861e361b5}
    #...
    the_annotation_object = layer.items()[i] #Fetch the object, like a: <qgis._core.QgsAnnotationLineItem object at 0x7f39690193f0>
    if the_annotation_object.type() == "polygon":
        polygon_annotations_list.append(the_annotation_object) #If it is a polygon annotation, append it to the list
    
#Create a temp polygon vector layer
uri = f"polygon?crs={layer.crs().authid()}"
vl = QgsVectorLayer(path=uri, baseName="my_polygon_annotations", providerLib="memory")
pr = vl.dataProvider()
for anno_polygon in polygon_annotations_list:
    anno_geometry = anno_polygon.geometry() #Extract the geometry
    #Create a new polygon feature for the temp layer
    f = QgsFeature()
    f.setGeometry(anno_geometry)
    pr.addFeature(f)

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vl) #Add the temp layer to the map.

You can then right-click the layer and export to file.

